# "undefined reference" even the lib has a symbol of the function

Tags: c, apr

When i linked the .o files,some problems happened:

```
gcc -L/usr/local/apr/lib -lapr-1 -pthread -laprutil-1  devpkg.o bstrlib.o db.o shell.o commands.o   -o devpkg
devpkg.o: In function `main':
/root/workspace/devpkg/devpkg.c:21: undefined reference to `apr_pool_initialize'
/root/workspace/devpkg/devpkg.c:22: undefined reference to `apr_pool_create_ex'
/root/workspace/devpkg/devpkg.c:36: undefined reference to `apr_getopt_init'
/root/workspace/devpkg/devpkg.c:38: undefined reference to `apr_getopt'
```

I used "objdump -T" to check the lib,it returned:

```
objdump -T libapr-1.so|grep apr_pool_initialize
000000000001db00 g    DF .text  00000000000000fb  Base        apr_pool_initialize
```

Why did this happen?

Comment: What if you put the `-l` rules at the end of the command instead?

Comment: `undefined reference` indicates a compilation error, not a linkage error. You should probably `#include` the lib's header file (at the top of file devpkg.c).

Comment: @barakmanos: No, unless I'm terribly confused "undefined reference" is definitely a linker error. (But it's probably best for me to be explicitly fallibilist before the day's first cup of coffee.)

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: I dunno, linkage errors are typically recognizable by their "hard-to-read" nature, but perhaps that's how it is just on some IDEs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely just a simple dependency issue. You might want to try listing all the libraries you link to after the .o files, in the right order based on their dependencies with one another.